# Can't set cookies in page.evaluate PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs

I need to get cookies and set them in PhantomJS for a request to a second server **site2.com**

```
page.open("http://site1.com", function(){
  page.evaluate(function(){
    var d = document.createElement('script');
    d.src = "http://site2.com/javascript_file.js"
    document.appendChild(d);
  });
});
```

**_http://site1.com** first server, set cookies in PhanotmJS (**successful**)

**_http://site2.com** second server, can't set cookies in phantomjs (**unsuccessful**)

Where is problem? How this fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript on the page can only set cookies for the domain that the JavaScript runs on. So if you set the cookies through `document.cookie` inside `page.evaluate()` and you're currently on site1.com, then you can *only* set cookies for site1.com.

Normally, you first have to open some page from a domain that you want to set the cookies on, but you can also utilitze the [`phantom.addCookie(obj)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html) function with the `domain` property of ".site2.com" set. You need to do this before adding the script tag through `page.evaluate()`. Keep in mind that `phantom` is not available inside of `page.evaluate()`.

Also, it may take a little while until the cookie is actually added, so I added a short `setTimeout()`.

Something like this should work:

```
page.open("http://site1.com", function(){
    phantom.addCookie({
        'name': 'Cookie-Name',
        'value': 'Cookie-Value',
        'domain': 'site2.com'
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
            var d = document.createElement('script');
            d.src = "http://site2.com/javascript_file.js"
            document.appendChild(d);
        });
    }, 200);
});
```